# Handle every user input as plain text

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, html

We have a really big web-application.
About 120.000 lines in total.

In this application the user has plenty possibilities to enter text.
In the user information, folders, groups and so on.

Some of the users want to name different objects like `Age < 20`.
There was a problem because ASP.NET blocks such input because of the "<" to prevent javascript-injections.

We found a way to shut those safety-mechanisms down but now our application is unsafe.

So the question is:
Is there any setting or property or whatever that can be set global (at one point for the whole application) that the application handles such input as plain text?

So when a user for example wants to name a folder `<script>alert("ALERT");</script>` it should be named that way and is shown just as `<script>alert("ALERT");</script>` but the script will not execute.

The same for HTML: if its named `Folder<br>One` it should look like: `Folder<br>One` and not like:
`Folder

One`

Of course i could use HTML-Encode/-Decode but i dont want to go through the whole project and add an Encoding/Decoding wherever an input is made or shown...
Also would a global solution pretent mistakes in the future development.

So again the Question: is there any way to handle every text just as *text*? And all that as global as possible?

Hope you could understand my problem and know any possibilities.

Comment: I remember correctly, when you use DataBinding, this is automatic

Comment: @SteveB could you please specify your answer? What exactly should i DataBind?

Comment: I meant that if you have a `<asp:Textbox>` inside a datatemplate (DataList, Datagrid, etc...), and if you bind the textbox to the inner context object, the encoding/decoding will be automatically handled by the databinding.

Comment: @SteveB But i have plenty of controls, that are not in a datatemplate. Also i have a few ones that are but those do not show the text correctly, either.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery, whenever you set your value to any span or div,

Use:

```
$('#myDiv').text('<script>alert("a")</script>');
```

And Don't use:

```
    $('#myDiv').html('<script>alert("a")</script>');
```

or

```
    $('#myDiv').innerHTML='<script>alert("a")</script>';
```

Comment: I think this is not the solution that he needs: http://jsfiddle.net/a7URQ/ and injects would be possible anyway without html encoding/decoding and escaping

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to use HTML encode decode than try `ValidateRequest="false"` You can do it like in code bellow:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" ValidateRequest="false" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

Another technique you may want to use is as following..

```
<script>
      function Encode() {
       var value = (document.getElementById('TextBox1').value);
       value = value.replace('<', "&lt;");
       value = value.replace('>', "&gt;");
       document.getElementById('TextBox1').value = value;
      }
 </script>

</head>
<body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="Encode()" />
 </form>
```

Server-Side

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  this.TextBox1.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(this.TextBox1.Text);
 }
```

Comment: Well the first part is what we used to shut down the safety mechanisms. And for the second one we would have to go through the complete application and add it everywhere. I was hoping for a more global solution.