# Global Setting: Ignore HTML/Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, telerik

I have asked a Question similar to this ([To find here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582226/handle-every-user-input-as-plain-text)).
But i have the feeling it was not really good and now i want to try it again, try it better.

My Problem is, that several users want to use Characters, which can be used to  inject HTML or Javascript into my application (<, >, etc.).
Is there any global setting, method or whatever that i can use to prevent HTML or Javascript from executing and just show it?

**For example:**
User Input:
`New<br>Folder`
Correct output:
`New<br>Folder`
Wrong output:
`New

Folder`

PS: I have ASP and Telerik controls.
Some of them show it correctly, for example Buttons.

Comment: I have though of that too, but the problem would be i'd have to go through about 120000 lines of code and find all inputs and add it there, i was hoping for a more global solution. Also most of the inputs are stored into Database and we want to store exactly, what the user entered.

Comment: If you don't want to apply the transformation at input, how about just before it is output?

Comment: @PaulS. That would do it but still there is the Problem that i would have to check this massive application and add it everywhere, where it is needed. And we have to take care of it in the future. As i said, i was hoping for a global solution.

Comment: If input sanitisation happens independently throughout the application and outputting is not unified then I don't see how you can avoid a line-by-line approach.